# HTML table not showing table header

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html table with 3 columns and any number of rows (based on a database output.)

```js
    var fields = ['a','b','c'];  //variable from database
    var data = ['p', 'q', 'r'];  //variable from database
    var who = ['x', 'y', 'z'];  //variable from database
    
    $(function() {
        var table = $("#resultTable");
        var rowNum = 3;
        var resultHtml = '';
    
     for(var i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
      resultHtml += ["<tr>",
      "<td>",
       fields[i],
      "</td>",
      "<td>",
       data[i],
      "</td>",
      "<td>",
       who[i],
      "</td>",
      '</tr>'].join("\n");
     }
    
     table.html(resultHtml);
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultTable">
            <tr>
              <th>Question</th>
              <th>Decision</th>
              <th>Whose Decision</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

The table shows the content properly but doesn't show the headers of each of the column such as `Question`, `Decision`, `Whose Decision`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replaced whole html.
You need to apped html like

```
table.append(resultHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `table.html(...)` you override the entire content of your table (include the header).

You can use something like that:

```js
var fields = ['a','b','c'];  //variable from database
var data = ['p', 'q', 'r'];  //variable from database
var who = ['x', 'y', 'z'];  //variable from database

$(function() {
    var table = $("#resultTable");
    var rowNum = 3;
    var resultHtml = $('<table>').append(table.find('tr').first()).html();

    for(var i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++) {
        resultHtml += ["<tr>",
     "<td>",
      fields[i],
     "</td>",
     "<td>",
      data[i],
     "</td>",
     "<td>",
      who[i],
     "</td>",
     '</tr>'].join("\n");
    }

    table.html(resultHtml);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="resultTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Question</th>
    <th>Decision</th>
    <th>Whose Decision</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use resultHtml to replace table HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the table in the javascript from what I can see. table.html(resultHtml) is replacing what you have in the html code.